# Spyder is restarting kernel without error message

Tags: python, spyder

Trying to run this example script in spyder IDE version 5.1.5

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec

# Fixing random state for reproducibility
np.random.seed(19680801)

dt = 0.01
t = np.arange(0, 10, dt)
nse = np.random.randn(len(t))
r = np.exp(-t / 0.05)

cnse = np.convolve(nse, r) * dt
cnse = cnse[:len(t)]
s = 0.1 * np.sin(2 * np.pi * t) + cnse

fig, (ax0, ax1) = plt.subplots(2, 1)
ax0.plot(t, s)
ax1.psd(s, 512, 1 / dt)

plt.show()
```

leads to

```
Restarting kernel...
```

without any further error message. Python version is 3.8.12, intalled with Anaconda.

Comment: What is your matplotlib version? 

Maybe this could be related with https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/16659 

For the solution: https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/16659#issuecomment-961306197

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Thank you [Daniel Althviz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15954282/daniel-althviz) for the hint.

This solution solved the problem:

```
conda install freetype=2.10.4
```

Ref: [spyder-ide GitHub issue 16659](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/16659#issuecomment-961306197)

Answer (score 0):

Probably a mismatch between `matplotlib`  and `spyder` versions. Using `conda`, uninstall both then install first `spyder` and then `matplotlib`. If using `pip` check the `matplotlib` version in the `spyder` documentation.