# Spyder kernel restarting by itself without warning

Tags: python, debugging, spyder, restart

Every time I try to run a script in Spyder, the kernel simply restarts itself without warning:

> Restarting kernel...

Once in a blue moon, it'll actually start the script, but it never manages to finish it and ends up restarting itself.

Does anyone know why this happens and how to fix it? I tried the answer from [Spyder is restarting kernel without error message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70166754/spyder-is-restarting-kernel-without-error-message) without any change.
I'm using Python 3.7.11 and Spyder 5.1.5 if that's relevant.

Comment: Are you running a GUI script?

Comment: @azelcer I am not, no. I am training machine learning models but the error persists with just about any script and model that I throw at it

Comment: I got the same behavior when the script crashes (hard fault). Try to run the script outside spyder and see if you see something bad happening.

Comment: @azelcer the scripts run fine on two other computers in Spyder and it works when running in an Anaconda command prompt